How to Use std::atomic_bool or std::atomic_flag?
Hi I need to use boolean flags in callback functions in my program to control program behavior. The callback threads are executed in different threads than the threads that set them up. In one of my callback functions the program sets the boolean flag and in the other it checks a different unrelated boolean flag. Currently I am using std::atomic_bool's for this purpose.
I've read about the possibility of deadlock with std::atomic variables. Is this something to worry about in my case? Is there anything else to worry about?
Am I doing things correctly in using the atomic_bool's like normal variables? If not how should I do things?
Should I be using std::atomic_flag instead?
And the compiler didn't throw an error initializing the standbyResumeTimerDelayBool in as below in the class member list not sure if this is correct or not.
Thanks!
//some code omitted to keep things simple
//first callback function, this boolean flag is checked at one other point in the program
static ULONG Replicator::standbyResumeCallbackFunction(PVOID context, ULONG type, PVOID setting);
ULONG Replicator::standbyResumeCallbackFunction(PVOID context, ULONG type, PVOID setting)
{
    if (type == PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC)
    {
        Replicator* replicator = reinterpret_cast<Replicator*>(context);
        replicator->standbyResumeSetTimerDelayBool();
    }
}

//Replicator class members
void standbyResumeSetTimerDelayBool() { standbyResumeTimerDelayBool = true; }
std::atomic_bool standbyResumeTimerDelayBool = false;

//behavior modified here
void Replicator::autoBackup()
{
    if (standbyResumeTimerDelayBool)
    {
        standbyResumeTimerDelayBool = false;
        //do stuff
    }
}


//second callback function
static DWORD CALLBACK copyProgress(
             LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred,
             LARGE_INTEGER streamSize, LARGE_INTEGER streamTransferred,
             DWORD streamNo, DWORD callbackReason, HANDLE src, HANDLE dst,
             LPVOID data);

DWORD Worker::copyProgress(LARGE_INTEGER totalSize, LARGE_INTEGER totalTransferred, LARGE_INTEGER, LARGE_INTEGER, DWORD, DWORD, HANDLE, HANDLE, LPVOID data)
{
    Worker *worker = static_cast<Worker *>(data);

    if (worker->getStop())
        return PROGRESS_CANCEL;
}

//Worker class members
bool getStop() { return cancel; }
std::atomic_bool cancel;

//cancel is set to false when backup begins
void Worker::startBackup()
{
    cancel = false;
}
//if user clicks cancel button cancel flag is set to false
void stop() { cancel = true; }


Should I be using std::atomic_flag instead? - usually no, atomic<bool> can do everything that atomic_flag can do, (e.g. exchange(1) is one way to implement test_and_set), and is also lock-free on all real-world platforms.

I've read about the possibility of deadlock with std::atomic variables.  Where?  Even if not lock-free, they can't deadlock because the available operations only operate on a single atomic object, and don't involve internal looping or retrying.  (Except as required to implement lock-free fetch_or or whatever with CAS or LL/SC retries on some machines. But CAS can't deadlock, and LL/SC can at worst livelock but good hardware should avoid that.)


I've read about the possibility of deadlock with std::atomic variables. Is this something to worry about in my case?

std::atomic can never deadlock on trivial types, see Can atomic read operations lead to deadlocks?, technically no, because atomic types are almost all trivial, and the only non-trivial std::atomic<shared_ptr> shouldn't cause a deadlock, unless your code has a logical bug that causes this deadlock, like deadlocking on resources.

Should I be using std::atomic_flag instead?

why ? std::atomic_flag has a harder interface, it is designed as a building block for mutexes and spinlocks. for an atomic bool you should use std::atomic_bool. and before C++20 you couldn't even read or set std::atomic_flag without doing an RMW with test_and_set which is a slow operation, which made std::atomic_flag slower than std::atomic_bool when used as an atomic bool. (i guess the naming gives it away).

the only concern i have is over this line.
if (standbyResumeTimerDelayBool)
{
    standbyResumeTimerDelayBool = false;
    //do stuff
}

If more than one thread is executing this code concurrently then more than one thread may end up executing this block, instead you should be doing an exchange here
if (standbyResumeTimerDelayBool && standbyResumeTimerDelayBool.exchange(false))
{
   // only 1 thread can enter this block
   // other threads will get back false from exchange, and won't enter
}

note that this exchange is slower than a normal write, so if only 1 thread was allowed to execute this code anyway then your original code is fine.
as pointed by Peter Cordes, you can also use a different memory order to improve performance.
if (standbyResumeTimerDelayBool.load(std::memory_order::memory_order_relaxed) && 
standbyResumeTimerDelayBool.exchange(false, std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire))

Personally, I wouldn't recommend you play with memory ordering unless you really know what you are doing.


And the compiler didn't throw an error initializing the standbyResumeTimerDelayBool in as below in the class member list not sure if this is correct or not.

It is correct if passing the containing struct to the other threads is synchronized. that is if the struct existed before the thread was created or it was passed to the other threads through an atomic or a lock or some thread-safe container that will establish synchronization between threads.

How could std::atomic<T> deadlock even for a large type where it isn't lock-free?  Even if there was a single mutex that all std::atomic operations had to compete for, it wouldn't deadlock because every operation only has to take that one lock, not also some other lock.  e.g. Can the implementation of std::atomic with respect to locks change a program's behavior from correct to incorrect? / Can atomic read operations lead to deadlocks?

If they care about performance, they should be using std::memory_order_acquire and std::memory_order_release.   Also, normally best to just attempt the RMW instead of first checking read-only: that could get a copy of the cache line in Shared state, so the exchange still needs an RFO (read for ownership) to get MESI Exclusive/Modified ownership, so twice as many off-core transactions in the uncontended case.

I guess they can't just use a normal library implementation of a spinlock, since they need to be able to set the flag ("unlock") multiple times.  Most libraries would consider that an error.  So yeah, rolling their own is justified even if they need mutual exclusion.  And they're not spin-waiting for an unlock, I guess just polling at some points?

@PeterCordes i originally though of std::atomic<shared_ptr> and similar future implementations, but i guess all the current implementations can't cause deadlock, so i should retract that statement.

@PeterCordes i initially though it gets polled at different points, so it is cheaper to read it without doing an RMW if it is only set rarely, like how worker early_quit_flag usually works.

Oh, right, yeah, again they're not just rolling their own spinlock.   If it's already false most of the time when another thread polls this variable, it is indeed better to x.load(relaxed) && x.exchange(false, acquire) to avoid the slow RMW and even any memory barriers in the do-nothing case (assuming they don't need to sync-with whatever thread wrote the false).  (On 32-bit ARMv7, even an acquire load needs a dmb ish full barrier, so relaxed is a significant win, unlike AArch32 state of ARMv8 where lda shouldn't be too bad.  On x86, even a seq_cst load is as cheap as relaxed.)

Your last edit still leaves it implying the reason that deadlocks are impossible is that atomic<bool> is lock-free.  I'm not aware of any case where std::atomic<> operations themselves can deadlock with each other.  You can of course write code that deadlocks if you write buggy code (e.g. where all threads end up spin-waiting for each other, e.g. if you implement your own spinlocks and use them wrong).  But that's not std::atomic's fault.  Individual std::atomic operations can't deadlock.

Deadlock is possible in single-threaded code when using a non-lockfree atomic in a signal handler. But of course, that would be buggy code.

Thanks guys, the last question about initialization was referring to this line: std::atomic_bool standbyResumeTimerDelayBool = false; This is present in the class member list declarations in the .h file. So wondering if I did it right or should do std::atomic_bool standbyResumeTimerDelayBool(false); Is either method proper?

@riverofwind both are exactly the same, just different syntax
